# How do I normalize eZ Find Search Score across multiple shared indexes?

Tags: solr, ezpublish

I am currently searching 3 different indexes on 3 different sites (Site A has access to the indexes of Site A, B, and C, and so on...) using eZ Publish extension, eZ Find (uses Apache Solr). This all works great, however the eZ Find (Solr) Score is different on all three sites when I use the same query (search for 'god' has different sort orders for all 3 sites).

Any thoughts as to how I might go about standardizing the scores or how to better predict them? All three sites share the same set of search templates so the search fetch function does not change, the CSS and content are the only differences between the sites.

Comment: The search scores ('more like this' scores too) dont mean anything in any absolute sense. They are only useful relatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick Update, I found the answer to this problem. eZ Find by default (on the ezfezpsolrquerybuilder.php) builds in a solr boost to the local site search results. Currently, the only way to prevent this from happening is to remove the code from the query builder script.